# Web page to test form submission online in HTTPS

Tags: testing, web-applications

I am building a web app that will autologin to websites.
For that I need to test my submission.
http://symlink.dk/code/php/submit/ is very usefull for http submits :

- it works for GET and POST
- it outputs my headers

I am looking for the same kind of service with HTTPS to avoid the burden of building/deploying my own HTTPS Server and Servlet.

Comment: http://browserspy.dk/password-ok.php let you test basic auth

Comment: This would be fairly easy to write yourself. What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but you can actually do exactly that with any `phpinfo()`-page and have a look at the `QUERY_STRING`-variable. If you google for ["https phpinfo"](http://www.google.de/search?q=https+phpinfo), you find plenty of phpinfo-pages you can use to test your form via

```
<form action="https://cgi.ccs.neu.edu/home/cgiadmin/examples/phpinfo.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="aHidden" value="aValue" />
    <input type="text" name="textField" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In that page, just search for "QUERY_STRING" and you'll have all the values you put into your form.

*(Note: If this was not the answer you were looking for, please edit your question towards a better specification of what you want.)*

Answer (score 2):

I believe @Lars has a great answer -- but **there shouldn't be any difference to you or your code as to whether you are submitting to a secure form or not**. The content is encrypted with the cert's public/private key, and happens totally behind the scenes.  Anything you send or receive will seem the same to you -- only protected.  Is there some other aspect of the process you have a question about?

Comment: There will be difference between HTTP Basic Authentification and form-based authentification. I have not noticed any difference between HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: I know that there should be no difference between HTTP and HTTPS but : I prefer to test and the answer let me also find websites having invalid certificates (to test more cases)